# Removing the last class attribute in test ARFF file for Weka ML Model not working in predicting model

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

Basically, I'm building a machine learning model in Java (Weka) to detect some patterns in strings. I have 2 class attributes that I'm trying to get my model to predict based on these patterns. My code works when I leave the attribute values in the ARFF file, but it doesn't when I take it out and replace it with question marks in the test file. When I do this, it gives me all the same values (cfb) in the output. I know the model isn't hard-coded but for testing purposes, I would like to remove these attribute values. I have already built the classifier and evaluated the model.

```
 /**
 * Make predictions based on that model. Improve the model
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void modelPredictions(Instances trainedDataSet, Instances testedDataSet, Classifier classifierType) throws Exception {
    // Get the number of classes
    int numClasses = trainedDataSet.numClasses();
    // print out class values in the training dataset
    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
        // get class string value using the class index
        String classValue = trainedDataSet.classAttribute().value(i);
        System.out.println("Class Value " + i + " is " + classValue);
    }
    // set class index to the last attribute
    // loop through the new dataset and make predictions
    System.out.println("===================");
    System.out.println("Actual Class, NB Predicted");
    for (int i = 0; i < testedDataSet.numInstances(); i++) {
        // get class double value for current instance
        double actualClass = testedDataSet.instance(i).classValue();
        // get class string value using the class index using the class's int value
        String actual = testedDataSet.classAttribute().value((int) actualClass);
        // get Instance object of current instance
        Instance newInst = testedDataSet.instance(i);
        // call classifyInstance, which returns a double value for the class
        double predNB = classifierType.classifyInstance(newInst);
        // use this value to get string value of the predicted class
        String predString = testedDataSet.classAttribute().value((int) predNB);
        System.out.println(actual + ", " + predString);
    }
}
```

[Image of the test ARFF File (Sorry, was getting errors in pasting the file content of the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIkjB.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the actual class in your test set with question marks, these get interpreted as missing values. A missing value in Weka is represented by `Double.NaN`. Casting a missing value (ie Double.NaN) to an `int` will result in `0`, which is the first nominal value of your class. Your *actual* class will always be the first class label.

The following code:

```java
double missing = Utils.missingValue();
System.out.println("missing value as double: " + missing);
System.out.println("missing value as int: " + ((int) missing));
```

Outputs this:

```
missing value as double: NaN
missing value as int: 0
```

Comment: The thing is, I'm not getting a NaN output or a '0'. Its printing out constant class attributes (cfb) only for some reason. How do I get it to work properly, while keeping the question marks in the Arff file?

Comment: No, when you cast the `NaN`, which is the missing value in your test set, to an `int`, it turns into a `0` (that's what my code demonstrates). In your code, you output the actual and predicted class value. When casting the actual value (ie missing) `NaN` to `0` the output of actual will always be the first class label. Go through the code with a debugger or add some `System.out.println` statements to see for yourself.